# Possible keyboard driver issue?

Tags: windows-7

Since I bought my new computer and installed win7 on it (1 year) weird things are going on. Every now and then it changes the language settings from Hungarian to English, the actual window loses focus, in-game I get popups by pressing totally unrelated buttons. It's like if somebody was pressing buttons on my behalf. I bought a new keyboard because of this, but it did not help. I installed Eset Smart Security with the fresh Win7, so I never browsed without an antivirus. I checked it with Malwarebytes and several other antivirus too but they have found nothing. I checked with focus.exe what happens when I lose focus, but it did not log any app taking the focus. Any idea of what is this? Is it possible that this is a keyboard driver issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cause of most of these problems is that Logitech uses even cheaper electronics in the K120 keyboards now. So I think the current keyboard has lower than 3 keys rollover. Which means if I press more than 2 keys at once, then things like I described in the question can happen. Some of the problems, like losing focus or changing language might be unrelated to this. I ordered an Anne Pro mechanical keyboard with a high rollover number. I'll see more when it arrives, but I think I can close this one.